# How can I provide methods in a base web api controller that can be accessed via attribute routing

Tags: inheritance, asp.net-web-api, routes

Base class:

```
public class DataApiControllerBase<T> : ApiController
    {
        public List<ValidationResult> Validate(T input)
        {
            ...

        }
    }
```

Derived class:

```
public class CustomerController: DataApiControllerBase<Customer>
    {
        [Route("api/customer/{id}")]
        public Customer Get([FromUri] Guid id)
       {

       }

    }
```

What would the route resolve to so I get a "validate" endpoint on each derived controller endpoint? Is this the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you could use method override to solve this

**Base class**

```
public class DataApiControllerBase<T> : ApiController
{
    public virtual List<ValidationResult> Validate(T input)
    {
        ...

    }
}
```

**Derived class**

```
public class CustomerController: DataApiControllerBase<Customer>
{
    Route("api/customer/validate")]
    [HttpPost]
    public override List<ValidationResult> Validate(Customer input)
    {
        base.Validate(input);
    }

   Route("api/customer/{id}")]
   public Customer Get([FromUri] Guid id)
   {

   }
}
```